# Unable to access array key when key name have special character

Tags: php, arrays

I'm experiencing issue with accessing to array key witch have apostrophe in the name, please see the var dump of array

```
array(5) { ["Shipper's choice"]=> array(2) { ["weight_sign"]=> string(1) "+" ["weight_count"]=> string(0) "" } ["Interesting wood grain"]=> array(2) { ["weight_sign"]=> string(1) "+" ["weight_count"]=> string(0) "" } ["Part blond face wood"]=> array(2) { ["weight_sign"]=> string(1) "+" ["weight_count"]=> string(0) "" } ["Mostly light colored"]=> array(2) { ["weight_sign"]=> string(1) "+" ["weight_count"]=> string(0) "" } ["Darkest wood"]=> array(2) { ["weight_sign"]=> string(1) "+" ["weight_count"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

If I try to access to `$array["Shipper's choice"]` it's working fine.

But if I have that key in a variable `$value = "Shipper's choice"` and try to access the array with `$array[$value]` I get the following error message
`Notice: Undefined index: Shipper's choice`.

This is how I actually want to access this value `$option_weights[$options["id"]][$value]["weight_sign"]`

I was unable to find the solution on my own so I'm asking for your help.

Thanks.

Edit:

This is working fine if the key doesn't have `'(apostrophe)` in the name

Edit 2:
Try to recreate with this:

This is the array I'm getting

```
$arr = [
            [
                "id" => "5f297bc71bd21",
                "raw" => [
                    "5f297"
                ],
                "values" => [
                    [
                        "label" => "Soonest Available",
                        "price" => 0,
                        "price_type" => "none",
                        "slug" => "5f297"
                    ]
                ],
                "label" => "Tine Color"
            ],
            [
                "id" => "5f297bc71bd3c",
                "raw" => [
                    "5f297"
                ],
                "values" => [
                    [
                        "label" => "Shipper's choice",
                        "price" => 0,
                        "price_type" => "none",
                        "slug" => "5f297"
                    ]
                ],
                "label" => "Want special wood?"
            ]
        ];
```

Then from database I'm pulling this value with WordPress `get_post_meta()` function

`$post_meta_value = a:5:{s:13:"5f297bc71bd21";a:8:{s:17:"Soonest Available";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:4:"Blue";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:5:"Green";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:3:"Red";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:6:"Yellow";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:5:"White";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:9:"Unpainted";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:12:"Custom Paint";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}}s:13:"5f297bc71bd34";a:5:{s:1:"D";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:2:"Db";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:2:"Eb";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:1:"C";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:1:"E";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}}s:13:"5f297bc71bd3c";a:5:{s:16:"Shipper's choice";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:22:"Interesting wood grain";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:20:"Part blond face wood";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:20:"Mostly light colored";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}s:12:"Darkest wood";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:0:"";}}s:13:"5f297bc71bd44";a:1:{s:3:"Yes";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:1:"5";}}s:13:"5f297bc71bd47";a:1:{s:3:"Yes";a:2:{s:11:"weight_sign";s:1:"+";s:12:"weight_count";s:1:"2";}}}`

`$option_weights = get_post_meta('post_id', '$post_meta_value', true)`

Here is the code to use:

```
foreach ($arr as $options) {
    if (isset($options["id"]) && array_key_exists($options["id"], $option_weights)) {
        $value = $options["values"][0]["label"];
        if (strlen($option_weights[$options["id"]][$value]["weight_count"]) > 0) {
            // Code breaks here
        }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219645/discussion-on-question-by-galabl-unable-to-access-array-key-when-key-name-have-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Jeto:

> [Your key probably contains HTML entities](https://3v4l.org/MH0An). And since you're probably dumping them on a webpage, you're not seeing them. Check the source of the page. Pretty sure you'll see Shipper's choice